# differences between UML 2.5.1 and UML 2.5

Tags: uml

I try to find a document listing the changes between UML 2.5.1 and UML 2.5, something like a release note.

I looked at the UL 2.5.1 document, look on OMG website, and bugs but I did not find a sum up of differences between the two versions.

Comment: It's only minor bug fixes thay made. Nothing you really need to care about (unless you're in an academic environment doing bug fix research).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is version of the standard document containing change bars that highlight all changes compared to the previous version of the document. It is accessible on the OMG page https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF/changebar